# How to get audio tags using audio fingerprint

Tags: java, audio-fingerprinting

I have an audio file with all id3 tags as null. I want to extract the [acoustic fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) and with an online service to get the id3 tags.

How can I do that in Java? Is there an online service who I can pass the audio fingerprint and it return the tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a non-commercial application, you can use [AcoustID](http://acoustid.org/webservice).

[Here](https://github.com/filebot/filebot/blob/master/source/net/filebot/web/AcoustIDClient.java) you can see some example code in Java. If you Google around, you will find more examples.

*Note: I created and run AcoustID*

Comment: The code seems to have been moved here: https://github.com/filebot/filebot/blob/master/source/net/filebot/web/AcoustIDClient.java

Answer (score 1):

As long as I know, there are two available open API:

1 - Look for fingerprint query in the [Echonest API](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4).

You need to create an API for yourself. Then, to identify a song, [use this](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/song.html#identify).

2 - The [AcousticID API](http://acoustid.org/webservice)

Comment: Echonest API has been shutdown because company was bought by Spotify: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Echo_Nest#cite_note-9