# How To Get MetaData From Music URL

Tags: android

I am Working On a Project Of Online Music Player. So it is possible that i retrieve metaData from music file URL and show the info about song in my project?
Please, someone suggest me about that, if it is possible
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get mp3's id3 tags using audio fingerprint in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871234/how-to-get-mp3s-id3-tags-using-audio-fingerprint-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MediaMetadataRetriever`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) to get metadata (ID3 tags):

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
    mmr.setDataSource(link, new HashMap<String, String>());
else
    mmr.setDataSource(link);

String albumName = 
mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));// to get album name
```

Comment: Sir this Code Dosen't Work Properly and Showing Error     
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: @AnkitSingh, this code works, but you might used it incorrectly. how the exception stacktrace, and line on which it happens

Comment: Sir Please Check These Links and tell me it is possible or not ---- [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35794) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514321/mediametadataretriever-on-streaming-source)

Comment: have you tried a solution provided there? `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
 mmr.setDataSource(link, new HashMap<String, String>());
else
 mmr.setDataSource(link);`

Comment: Sir Instead Of Context i am using Direct Url and 2nd Argument new Hashmap<String , String> for >14 verrsions and for <14 versions only using **URL** in Argument .. So Please Sir Edit ANswer and Thanks Again